# Facing problem in Watchdog implementation in AUTOSAR

Tags: watchdog, autosar

I want to implement watchdog interface in AUTOSAR using watchdog modules like Watchdog Driver, Watchdog Interface and Watchdog Manager.
I implemented with one checkpoint and to test the functionality and reset.

My test code is:

```
if(WDG_TEST == TRUE)
{
    (void)Rte_Call_WdgM_AliveSupervision_CheckpointReached(0);  
}
else
{
    (void)WDG_TRIGGER();    /*Trigger Watchdog*/
}
```

But I am facing a problem of not being able to rest the watchdog.
Am I missing something over here??

Comment: Not really sure, what your testcode shall achieve. Runnable Entities can be configured to report to WdgM for alive/deadline/logical supervision. The WdgM will check this, and if one has expired, will set the trigger condition to a Wdg over WdgIf. The Wdg will either trigger or not trigger the Watchdog according to that trigger condition.

Comment: How can a test code be to test the watchdog to initiate a trigger in toggle mode?

Comment: Why does your test code actually call WDG_TRIGGER() in the else path?